# Getting error while setting up local environment for creating Shopify app

Tags: shopify, liquid, git-bash, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am a beginner in creating a shopify app, while setting up my development environment I got an error of this thing:
X System call failed: tar -xf C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/shopify/ngrok.zip

please tell me how can I resolve this issue?

I have tried running this command
shopify app serve